# Get highlighted text in textfield or texteditor in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, highlight, xcode12

I am working on the Note app using SwiftUI. I want to highlight the selected text in TextField or in the TextEditor and get the highlighted text.

I searched a lot but don't find any solution. If anyone help, I am very thankful to him

Comment: SwiftUI does not provide such feature for now (SwiftUI 2.0) - use instead UIKit controls.

Comment: @Asperi Can you please explain how to use UIKIT control in SwiftUI

Comment: @MuhammadFarooq The idea is to use [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) to allow UIKit controls in SwiftUI. See [this project](https://github.com/kyle-n/HighlightedTextEditor) for an example.

Comment: Can you provide an answer with details @Muhammad Farooq?

Comment: @Lkabo I am working on the SwiftUI. I want to select some text in the text field or text editor and highlight it. But the SwiftUI doesn't give the highlight feature But we can select some specific text in the UITextView and highlight it. I rendered the UITextView in the swiftui and got this feature.

Comment: @MuhammadFarooq I think he meant to answer your own question with a solution. Even thought SwiftUI solution still doesn't exist, your UIKit solution could be handy